# Detecting and filling in missing data in PostgreSQL street address data

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, count, sql-insert

I've got a database of Finnish street addresses built from a public data source. The format is `<street name> <number> [<a possible suffix of letters and dashes>]`, e.g. `Aurakatu 8` or `Aurakatu 12b`. After some filtering of the source data to remove anomalous or garbage data, the DB is around 1.8M rows. Around 195k of them contain the suffix.

The source data is reasonably but not fully complete. The issue I'm trying to deal with is this: a street name + number combination exists IRL (e.g. `Aurakatu 12`), but the data only contains letter-suffixed forms (`Aurakatu 12a` and `Aurakatu 12b`). All three forms are valid and point to discrete locations in Google Maps, for example.

To summarize, this is what I'm trying to achieve: find every street name + number combo in the address table where only suffixed versions exist, and create a non-suffixed entry.

In the case of the above example, the query or queries would discover that for a hypothetical `Aurakatu 12` street name/number combo, only suffixed versions `12a` and `12b` exist, and would create the plain `12` version.

The data importing is run very infrequently while setting up (or significantly updating) server instances, so maximum efficiency is not paramount.

`street_name` and `number` are separate table columns in the `addresses` table. The numbers themselves are not necessarily contiguous; it's common for something like `Somestreet 24` to exist but `Somestreet 25` to not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
insert into addresses (street_name, street_number)
select street_name, regexp_replace(street_number, '\D+$', '')
from addresses
group by 1, 2
having count(*) filter(where street_number ~ '\d$') = 0
```

The `regexp_replace()` expression strips the (potential) trailing non-digit characters at the end of the string; then the query groups together all rows that have the same `street_name` and (stripped) `street_number`. The `having` clause then filters out groups that already contain the unsuffixed `street_number` (that is, a street number that ends with a digit): what remains is inserted into the table.

You can (and should!) run the `select` query independently first to see what would be inserted.

Comment: This is producing `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("` on line 4 for the first parenthesis that follows `count(*)` while running the `SELECT` query on its own. Removing the parens from around the last regex comparison just cause the syntax error to be on `street_number` instead.